# COUNT() Likes in query returns unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am creating some sort of a social media like facebook and I'm trying to get the number of likes a post has using the following query.

```
SELECT posts.object_ID, posts.user_ID, posts.datetime, posts.text, 
    COUNT(likes.object_ID) AS likes, 
    SUM(IF(likes.user_ID=?, 1, 0)) AS allowLike, users.first_name, 
    users.last_name, userinfo.image_ID 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=posts.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN friends ON (friends.user_ID_1=? OR friends.user_ID_2=?) 
    AND friends.approved=1 
LEFT JOIN userinfo ON users.ID=userinfo.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.object_ID=posts.object_ID 
WHERE ". $str ." 
GROUP BY posts.object_ID 
ORDER BY posts.datetime DESC 
LIMIT 0,30
```

The value of `$str` is just a mechanism to filter out friends and stuff, e.g.:

```
$str = "(posts.user_ID=friends.user_ID_1 OR posts.user_ID=friends.user_ID_2) OR posts.user_ID=? ";
```

What happens now is that `COUNT(likes.object_ID)` returns 4 and `SUM(IF(likes.user_ID=?, 1, 0))` returns 4 as well.

This, surprisingly enough, is the actual amount of likes times the number of friends I have(4), I assume, since a post with 2 likes shows up as 8 likes. Yesterday I had 3 friends and it showed up as 3. And it's only happening when the post is my own.

I use a very similar query for fetching the comments, yet nothing strange is happening there.

Any ideas?

EDIT: It is not just limited to my own posts. I just found a case where it is in someone elses post. Still, it is NOT happening to every post... which is weird. Also, it is not bound to my own likes...

EDIT2: Upon 'reliking' the post I was speaking about in EDIT1, it showed up as one, and after a couple of refreshes it still showed up as 1 like. Weird..

Comment: Not answering your question here, but considering the complexity of your query, and since you mentioned that this is for a social media site, might I suggest caching the total "likes". It's not like anyone really needs real time data of when something was liked through this query it looks like.

Comment: At first I was indeed using a trigger, but I recently changed my table structure, making it very complex to impossible to use triggers. Unless I use a trigger for every object I have. (I have a main table, objects where I genererate an ID and use this when a new object (photo, post etc.) is created. I could just add a likes column to every object, and use a trigger on every object I have (Like SET likes=likes+1 WHERE posts.object_ID=NEW.object_ID; SET likes=likes+1 WHERE images.object_ID=NEW.object_ID; etc. etc. etc. This would work but it's a pain to expand. Think this is better?

Comment: The above would cause problems upon deleting an object, forcing me to use a GLOBAL mysql variable. It's just not as elegant. But possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I decided to give up on this, and just go for a solution similar to the one described by myself and @Duniyadnd in the comments on my question.

I have a table objects. It only contained an ID. I added a field 'likes'. And created two triggers: One for the newLike, and one for a deletedLike which would update the likes column at the given object_ID.

Now my query is as such:

```
SELECT 
    posts.object_ID, posts.user_ID, posts.datetime, posts.text, objects.likes, 
SUM(IF(likes.user_ID=?, 1, 0)) AS allowLike, users.first_name, users.last_name,   
    userinfo.image_ID 
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN users ON users.ID=posts.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN friends ON (friends.user_ID_1=? OR friends.user_ID_2=?) AND friends.approved=1 
LEFT JOIN userinfo ON users.ID=userinfo.user_ID 
LEFT JOIN objects ON objects.ID=posts.object_ID 
LEFT JOIN likes ON likes.object_ID=posts.object_ID 
WHERE ". $str ." 
GROUP BY posts.object_ID ORDER BY posts.datetime DESC LIMIT 0,30
```

So I cleared my likes table to start over, yet, allowLike (`SUM(IF(likes.user_ID=?, 1, 0))`) still returns 4. There is only 1 entry in the likes table, I'm still curious why this is hapenning? Again, I have 4 friends.

Or would I better place this in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be related to your WHERE clause. A parameter is not parsed; your WHERE is simply a long varchar, your RDMS is interpreting this as TRUE.

Comment: I do not think this is the case, as I use different WHERE clauses succesfully, for instance: `$str = "posts.group_ID='?'";`, this gives me the same weird offset.

Answer (score 0):

The joins are causing multiple intermediate rows to be created from the cross joins of the rows in one table with those of another table. Therefore your 4 friends are causing the 1 like to be turned into 4 intermediate rows, and then it is summed up to get a result of 4.

Instead of all the joins, try using a select within the first select, like this query on posts/comments/likes:

```
select postid, postmessage,
 (select count(commentid) from comment where post.postid = comment.postid) as numcomments,
 (select sum(value) from like where post.postid = like.postid) as popularity
from post
group by postid
```

(I have like.value as being 1 or -1 as up votes and down votes)

Hope that helps :)